# Spring Security. How do I get a user email address?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

**How do I get the user email address in the controller?**

I am trying to get the email address of a user in the controller who is trying to log in, but for some reason was blocked. I want to inform the user that the user with this email address has been blocked. But for this, I need to get his email address.

**Question**! How do I get the user email address in the controller?

I have **SecurityConfig**, **UserDetail**, **LoginController**.

Here I have added the whole project - https://github.com/romanych2021/mytest made specifically for this question

**SecurityConfig**

```
    package com.mytest.security;

    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private final
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
            this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()

                    .mvcMatchers("/login").anonymous()
                    .mvcMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")

                    .and()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .usernameParameter("email")
                    .passwordParameter("password")

                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/403")

                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")

                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
        }


    }
```

**UserDetail**

```
    package com.mytest.security;

    import com.mytest.model.User;
    import com.mytest.service.UserRepository;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;

    @Service
    public class UserDetail implements UserDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

            User user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);


            if (user == null){
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("There is no such user " + email);
            }


            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    user.getEmail(),
                    user.getPassword(),
                    user.getEnabled(),
                    user.getAccount_non_expired(),
                    user.getCredentials_non_expired(),
                    user.getAccount_non_locked(),
                    getAuthorities());

        }


        private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(){

            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<>();
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

            return authList;

        }

    }
```

**LoginController**

```
    package com.mytest.controller;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

    @Controller
    public class LoginController {

        @GetMapping(value = "/login")
        public String loginGet () {

            // How do I get the user's email address here?

            return "login";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use the provided UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and didn't do any overrides to this, and that the user is already logged in to your system; you can access the username as follows:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/login")
public String loginGet (Authentication auth) {
    String username = auth.getName();
    return "login";
}
```

Spring will automatically inject the default Authentication token which is `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` here.

---

**EDIT**: Seems I mistook the question for already logged in. In case this is a login failure issue you can do the following:

Step 1: Create a new AuthenticationException as follows:

```
public class UserBlockedException extends UsernameNotFoundException {
    public UserBlockedException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Step 2: Throw the above exception in the UserDetail @Service class with the message you need to show to the user if user is blocked.

Step 3: Show the error message in the login?error=true form:

```
<div th:if="${param.error}">
  Login Failed. Reason: <span th:text="${session["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message"></span> 
</div>
```

Spring Security will use the default `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler` to handle your error. It will save your exception as a session attribute which you access in thymeleaf as shown in Step 3.

Comment: You can include the email address or username as part of the message in `UserBlockedException` since it is thrown in `UserDetail`. If you are not comfortable with extending `UsernameNotFoundException` to provide `UserBlockedException`, you may extend `AuthenticationException`, but then the validation will need to be done on a custom `AuthenticationProvider`. Follow this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider

Answer (score 0):

```
public static User getCurrentUser() {
    return (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

You need to configure a new User class that implements UserDetails and have UserDetailService's loadUserByUsername method return an instance of this User. Refer to this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database).

Edit:
I misread the original post. The revised answer by jms should handle your issue.

Comment: I promise you that this works. This will allow you to call getCurrentUser() in your controller, access the User field, and retrieve their email. If you share what you're struggling with I can help.

Comment: @Max My answer was incorrect, I misunderstood your issue. You say that you want to inform the user if they have been "blocked" for some reason attempting a login. Blocked by what, specifically? An invalid email? A disabled account?

Comment: Yes, I want to inform him from this area. enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked

Comment: These methods will throw DisabledException, AccountExpiredException, CredentialsExpiredException, LockedException when they try to login and redirect to /login with the "error" parameter. Follow jms's edit below and add a div with th:if="${param.error}" and set the text inside with th:text="${session["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}". For example, if the user's account is disabled, a DisabledException will be thrown and thymeleaf will parse the text as "User is disabled".

Answer (score 0):

Check this and implement,

```
public String getDetails(Authentication authentication, Principal principal) {
    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    List<String> roles = userDetails.getAuthorities().stream()
            .map(item -> item.getAuthority())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return userDetails.getEmail();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember when you are using Spring Security you do not need a controller -  a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is registered in the security filter chain and does the authentication job. So I guess you can check it and adjust your logic accordingly. [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/a82cab7afdb1fc58830b1c415f1874d36b2c6c92/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java#L68)

Comment: Any parameter cannot be passed from this filter to the controller. I tried to do it and it didn't work out for me.